# Differential geometry problem about locally canonic form of metric

Tags: differential-geometry

could someone explicitly show me how to do this calculation? I apologize for the not very clean format, but I'm a newbye (I accept any advice or tutorial you offer me to improve in the future).

$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{g_{ij}(x)=\pm \delta_{ij}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g_{ij} }{\partial x^{k}{\partial x^{l}}}|_P 
\delta x^k\delta x^l+...}}$$

Prove the locally canonic form of the metric above.

Taylor expand the components of the metric $g_{ij}$ = $g_{ij}(x)$ and the (unknown) change
of coordinates $x^{i′}$ = $x^i{′}(x)$ around the point P in the original reference frame $x^{i}$ and the
components of the metric $g_{i′j′}$ = $g_{i′j′}(x′)$ in the new (unknown) coordinates $x^{i′}$ again around
P. Then use the general transformation law for the components,

$$g_{i'j'}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{i'}}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^{j'}}g_{ij}$$

to compare terms of equal orders and show that there is a sufficient number of coefficients in
the Taylor expansion of the change of coordinates to put the matrix $g_{i′j′}$ in canonical form
at P and make its first derivatives vanish at P.

Comment: The form of the metric you've given (although in modern notation we do not write $\delta x^k$, but we write $dx^k$) is immediate in Gauss normal (geodesic) coordinates. Look at any reasonable differential geometry book for that. You do *not* want to approach this by starting with an arbitrary system of local coordinates.

Comment: The calculations shown here might be helpful: https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/01/28/RiemannCurvature.html.

Comment: @TedShifrin the notation used is that of my professor, who mainly uses "geometrical methods of mathematical physics by Bernard Schutz". What you read is part of a paragraph made in class. The problem is that it only deals with the theoretical part, and some exercises (like this one) are presented in a rather confusing way, both the requests and the suggestions.

Comment: @TedShifrin, the right side of the equation is the Taylor series expansion of the function $g_{ij}(P + \delta x^k e_k)$, so it's not so bad.

Comment: Oh, good point, this is in the expansion of $g_{ij}$, not the metric tensor itself, so my $dx^k$ quibble was absolutely wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Deane!